# How to remove a certificate Store added by makecert

Tags: c#, powershell, x509certificate, windows-server-2008-r2

Using the `-ss` option of Microsoft tool `MakeCert.exe` (-ss specifies the subject's certificate store name that stores the output certificate), I create my own store on a server. I'am able to remove my certificate programaticaly, but I'am not able to remove the store itself. According to the error message this not seems to be supported by the provider.

I can't even use the MMC snapin (certmgr.msc) to remove it. Does anybody know how to do that ?

```
PS cert:\LocalMachine> Remove-Item .\SigningStore
Remove-Item : L'exécution du fournisseur s'est arrêtée, car le fournisseur ne prend pas en charge cette opération.
Au niveau de ligne : 1 Caractère : 12
+ Remove-Item <<<<  .\SigningStore
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [Remove-Item], PSNotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupported,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

The only way I found was to use [CertUnregisterSystemStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377162%28VS.85%29.aspx) Win32 API

Comment: You wrote no comment to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9749076/315935). Is the problem already solved?

Comment: Sorry, I just do not take time to test it. I'll do it and answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [this](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/58/removing-a-windows-system-certificate-store) and add-type with c# code with pinvoke (already done!) of `crypt32.dll`

Comment: Thanks @Christian, I found this one, I wrote about CertUnregisterSystemStore in my last sentence.

Comment: @JPBlanc. Yes I read you last sentence but link to msdn doesn't have the pinvoke done with all flags value! Less work, more time available! :-)

Comment: Note that in LinqPad, you need to either have ``System.Runtime.InteropServices`` imported, or fully specify the DllImport, e.g. ``[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)]``

Answer (score 10):

I accidentally created a store called Personal and wanted to get rid of it (of course). Two personal stores to look for ughhh. Anyways, I added a certificate that I had created to that store, copied the thumbprint (and removed the spaces) and then searched the registry for the thumbprint. I discovered I could make them go away by deleting the key (in my case Personal) at [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Personal] (if in the local machine) or at [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Personal] is in current user. I knew that it wasn't the other one called Personal because the real personal store is actually stored as My.

EDIT: I had to remove a few other keys to solve this but basically search carefully and examine each entry that matches what you are trying to get rid of. For each match, export to a reg file and then delete and test.

This post was a bit helpful as well: http://banachowski.com/deprogramming/2011/01/deleting-unwanted-certificate-stores-from-windows/

Answer (score 6):

Use a PowerShell cmdlet:

```
Remove-Item -Path cert:\LocalMachine\StoreYouWantToDelete
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the certificate manager tool? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78byta0%28VS.80%29.aspx (see certmgr.exe /del )

Comment: Thanks, I'am able to remove a user certificate with this tool, but not a computer store.

Comment: Your question is also tagged with "PowerShell". Maybe this can help you: http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/category/certificate-management/ (see Remove-QADLocalCertificateStore )

Comment: @DavidBrabant Your last comment is an answer!